# Duplicate Column Data in Inner Join

Tags: sql

```
select questions.quesid, questions.question, questionsoptions.optionid
from questions
  inner join questionsoptions on questions.quesid = questionsoptions.quesid;
```

Above query gives output like this: [image]

How can i remove the duplicate data from the column quesid, questions and column optionid remain same

Comment: use group by clause in your select statement.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, and in this case I don't even see the point of the join.  Update with your expected output.

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: quesid 1.,  question Please indicate your Occupation or occupation of the Chief Wage Earner of the Household optionid 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 and quesid 2. Please indicate the assets owned by you/ your Household 1,2,3,4 like this

Comment: if you remove the duplicate what will happen to the optionid?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Put one of the tags back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to include all of the `optionid` values within the same row, it can be done with `GROUP_CONCAT` which will create a string with all the ids separated by a comma.

```
SELECT questions.quesid, questions.question, GROUP_CONCAT(questionsoptions.optionid)
FROM questions INNER JOIN questionsoptions ON questions.quesid = questionsoptions.quesid
GROUP BY questions.quesid, questions.question;
```

Comment: thanks @dat3450 its working. i am using array_agg() instead of group_concat()

Answer (score 2):

In your result, all the rows with same quesid, question have different optionid. That makes all these rows distinct. So you if you want to have one row for a quesid, question you need to aggregate the results.

For Example

```
select questions.quesid, questions.question, count(questionsoptions.optionid) 
from questions inner join questionsoptions on questions.quesid = questionsoptions.quesid
group by questions.quesid, questions.question;
```

Comment: hi @pkgajulapalli i want to show the optionid same as shown in table not to count it....thanks

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? @Ricky

Comment: quesid 1., question Please indicate your Occupation or occupation of the Chief Wage Earner of the Household optionid 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 and quesid 2. Please indicate the assets owned by you/ your Household 1,2,3,4 like this

Comment: you can use group_concat instead of count

Comment: thanks @pkgajulapalli its working. i am using array_agg() instead of group_concat()